# Multiple flex not working

Tags: css, flexbox, stylus

I am trying to make an upload file form. Currently it looks like this

[image: form Image]

To make it easy for you, below is the form with classname of the target part. I have also attached component structure below that and my stylus file also.

[image: upload form with classname]

I want the browse button to be in the same line with textbox. I tried doing it but it is not working. THis is what I tried

My component render

```
 <div className='control-container'>
      <div className='control-label'> Video File</div>
      <div className='control-browse'>
           <input type="text" className="form-control" id="fileName" value={selectedFile.name} readOnly/>
           <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" style={{backgroundColor:"#fe8012", borderColor:"#fe8012"}} onClick={(e) => this.upload.click()}>Browse</button>
           <input id="myInput" type="file" ref={(ref) => this.upload = ref} style={{visibility: 'hidden', width:0}} onChange={this.handleFileSelect.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div className='control-container'>
      <div className='control-label'> Poster</div>
      <div className='control-browse'>
           <input type="text" className="form-control" id="posterName" value={selectedPoster.name} readOnly/>
           <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" style={{backgroundColor:"#fe8012", borderColor:"#fe8012"}} onClick={(e) => this.upload.click() }>Browse</button>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div className='control-container'>
      <div className='control-label'> Type</div>
      <div className='control'>
           <Select
              name='assign-user'
              clearable={false}/>
      </div>
 </div>
```

and this is my stylus

```
.control-container
    display flex
    align-items center

    .control-label
        width 120px
    .control
        display flex
        flex 1
            flex-direction row
    .control-browse
        display flex
        flex-direction row
        flex 1

    & + .control-container
        margin-top 30px
```

Comment: that's not a "stylus" (a pen), but it isn't css either.

Comment: Could you show the css that is compiled from your code? It could be that there is something compiling incorrectly